# Is there any condition where alcohol oxidizes in presence of chromium trioxide to give carboxylic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry

My text book says that alcohol in presence of $\ce{CrO3}$ will only give aldehyde. But I then saw this question in which $\ce{CrO3}$ oxidizes alcohol directly to carboxylic acid.

I need to know in which conditions it will give aldehyde and in which conditions it will give carboxylic acid.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43283/mechanism-for-oxidation-of-primary-alcohols-to-carboxylic-acids/43294?r=SearchResults#43294 ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/104277/is-there-a-way-to-oxidize-salicyl-alcohol-to-salicylic-acid-without-using-chromi?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 2):

Generally you need anhydrous conditions to get the aldehyde because aldehydes that can form hydrates are further oxidised to the acid. Anhydrous conditions with a complexing agent such as pyridine to aid solubility (e.g. Collins reagent [1](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/chemicals/oxidations/collins-reagent.shtm)) will give good yields of aldehydes.

Aq. acid conditions (known as Jones reagent) [2](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/jones-oxidation.shtm) give the carboxylic acid

See this answer  [How does PCC not oxidize aldehyde?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67688/how-does-pcc-not-oxidize-aldehyde?rq=1)

The use of Chromium reagents has greatly diminished due to their toxicity and waste disposal problems.

Comment: Sir, is chromic anhydride in glacial acetic acid or PCC a better reagent to convert alcohols involving C-C double bond to ketones without affecting the double bond? On internet, I found that PCC is not good as compared to first because it can oxidise double bond also . Please tell.

Comment: @An_Elephant If this relates to a reaction you actually need to do I would not consider using a chromium reagent at all. If this is a theoretical exercise I would use a very precisely measured amount of PCC in DCM as it will preferentially oxidise the alcohol. I am not aware of any references on PCC oxidising alkenes.This reference says it will not  https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Alcohols/Reactivity_of_Alcohols/The_Oxidation_of_Alcohols/Oxidation_by_PCC_(pyridinium_chlorochromate)   Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: Sir, unfortunately I don't. In our country there is a entrance examination in which it was asked and the answer key says that first one is best . The reason provided by all the solutions website is first and they say that it is because PCC have chances to reduce alkenes also . Here is a list of those ( they are not official website of exam organiser) : https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/the-best-reagent-to-convert-pent3en2ol-into-pent3en2one-is/

Comment: https://byjus.com/question-answer/the-best-reagent-to-convert-pent-3-en-2-ol-into-pent-3-en-2-2/

Comment: https://www.vedantu.com/question-answer/the-best-reagent-to-convert-pent-3-en-2-ol-into-class-12-chemistry-cbse-5f626a8896466665ae05aa12

Comment: Sir, similarly there are dozens of more. However, the organisers only release answers and nor full solutions. So these cannot be considered as very authentic/reliable. Thanks sir

Comment: That sums up the difference between exam chemistry and real world chemistry. Nobody should be using chromium reagents.

Comment: Means in theoretical terms, first one is better? I think such questions are just non-sense and should never be asked in exams.